# Spotipy continuously forces pasting of Redirect URL

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm trying to create an automated Spotify controller using the Spotipy library, and to start, I'm just trying to get this sample code running, but I can't:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from pprint import pprint
from time import sleep

scope = "user-read-playback-state,user-modify-playback-state"
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))

# Shows playing devices
res = sp.devices()
pprint(res)

# Change track
sp.start_playback(uris=['spotify:track:6gdLoMygLsgktydTQ71b15'])

# Change volume
sp.volume(100)
sleep(2)
sp.volume(50)
sleep(2)
sp.volume(100)
```

I have my `Client_ID`, Client_SECRET, and `Redirect_URI` set as `env` variables, and it works as intended with one major issue.

Whenever 'sp' is invoked, it opens up a window and redirects me to my Redirect `URI`, and before the code will traverse past the line that invokes 'sp,' it requires me to paste the URL into the terminal. So, in the above code for example, it opens a window & asks me to paste when it retrieves the devices on my account, then again when it starts the playback, and three more times whenever it changes the volume at the end of the code. It completes all of these tasks successfully, but not without requiring me to paste the site I was redirected to first. Obviously, since I'm trying to build an limited-user-interaction Spotify controller, this doesn't really work too well. In the docs, `Spotipy` notes that the OAuth client credentials manager should work as I intend it to, where you give it permissions once and then it works fine after that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The line of `sp = spotipy.Spotipy()` is wrong.
That has to be:
`sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))`